# Difference between 実は and 実に

Tags: meaning

A few minutes ago on TV I heard the phrase `実に`. I know that `実` is used like `実は` - means `the fact, that..`. But what the person have mean by saying `実に`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`実に` is used as an adverb, for example to reinforce a feeling or emphasize a fact.

```
実に美しい。 [It|He|She|etc] is _truly_ beautiful.
```

`truly`, `really`, `indeed` would all be acceptable translations (depending on the context).
@DariusJahandarie suggested `truly` and it fits actually very well as it shares the same "truth" root (see my comment about `実` itself).

`実は` is used as `To tell the truth` or `To be honest` for example in English, in order to reveal a truth that until now was somehow hidden.

```
実は昨日でした。 [To tell the truth|Actually], it was yesterday. (with the added meaning that you didn't know and now I reveal it to you)
```

The difference comes from the function of the particle appended to it. `実` here has the same meaning as `ほんとう` which you may be more acquainted with. And with which you encounter the same difference when appended by either `に` or `は`:

```
ほんとうに優しい。 [He|She]'s very/really kind.
ほんとうは優しいよ。 In truth / Actually, [I|he|she] [am|is] kind. (meaning e.g. "[I don't|He doesn't] look so, but in truth ...")
```

Same again with `実際{じっさい}`: `実際に` and `実際は` have similar nuances.

You may encounter `実` in other expressions again such as `実のところ`, or `実をいうと`, which both mean the same as `実は`. You see here that `実をいうと` translates directly into the English `to tell the truth`.

To sum it up, I could answer to @DariusJahandarie bewilderment about my initial omission of `truly` as a potential translation for `実に` by:

```
実{じつ}に合{あ}う訳{やく}ですね。実{じつ}は全{まった}く思{おも}いつきませんでした。
```

, and by the way those wouldn't be interchangeable ;)

PS: stumbled upon [this](http://www.tanos.co.uk/jlpt/skills/vocab/sentences/?vocabid=86315) extensive list of examples of usage of `実に` along with translations, it might be a good resource to forge a better feeling of the various contexts the expression can be used.

Comment: You've answered the basic question but your answer would be more useful if you explained a bit more about 実(じつ） -eg does it mean the same in both cases?, is it only used with these particles?

Comment: The question is specifically about the difference between `実に` and `実は`, and I think it's better to understand them idiomatically. At the core though, `実` refers to the truth (`ほんとう`) as opposed to lies (`嘘{うそ}`), or truthfulness of feelings / intentions (integrity, sincerity). Which boils down to the same basic idea of truth. It's more a nuance induced by the particle (`に` vs `は`). I'll add en example with `ほんとう` it may make it easier to grasp a feeling of the difference.

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: Both answers are fine, but I have to say I'm a little confused that no one has opted to translate 実に as "truly", which seems like the obvious thing to do to me. :-)

Comment: @DariusJahandarie "true"... I'll add it ! thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

実に means "very", "really, "surely" in English and 本当に in Japanese.

For example, あなたは実に美しい。(You are very beautiful).